# Disk is always up and down on %

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure, sata, desktop-computer

I always / almost all the time have my disk % really high or just stuck in 100%. My PC is almost 1 year old and I've been struggling with this for a few months and tried many things.
My Disk is a **Seagate barracuda 1TB 7200RPM 64MB SATA III 3.5**
It reads and writes around 900kbs but sometimes goes to 1.5mb, then quickly down again.

Pc Specs:

- Seagate barracuda 1TB 7200RPM 64MB SATA III 3.5
- MSI A68HM-P33 FM2+
- ASUS GEFORCE GTX960 TURBO OC 2GB
- AMD-ASERIES A10-7700K SKT FM2
- GSKILL PC3-12800 8GB RIPJAWSX CL9 (2x4gb) DDR3
- CORSAIR CX-600W 80PLUS BRONZE
- DVDRW ASUS 24X dual layer
- N200 USB 3.0

I have Windows 10. I tried disable many background programs without result.

Comment: Well I'm not really capable of doing that right now but why!? The Hdd is messed up?

Comment: If a disk is very busy but archieves extremely low thoughput then that matches the symptoms of bad sectors and attempts to read them (over and over until it either succeeds or times out). This should show up if you check the S.M.A.R.T. values for that disk.

Comment: the HDD is not messed up, it is simply too slow. Traditional HDD have  limited IOPS because of the rotating parts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS if you don't want to replace the HDD, accept the slowness. there is no way to fix this technical limitation because the HDD controller reports the high usage to the operating system: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis#time=06m55s

Comment: But it's normal that I went so well for months and now he's like this?

Answer (score -1):

I usually check the problems with Crystal disk info

http://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html

if it shows okay, it might just require defragment or running tight antivirus and malware scans. also if you have DVR enabled you can try to switch it off via http://www.howtogeek.com/273180/how-to-disable-windows-10s-game-dvr-and-game-bar/

Comment: I already disabled the DVR I think I already use a program like that to see if the Disk is okay and it didn't give me error it said it was fine and I already defragment with a program :/ I will try again this afternoon, thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Disk defragmentation is not going to help.

I see two possibilities:

1. Malware infection. Use antivirus software to check for it.
2. Bad sectors. Any hard disk checking/monitoring program you use will have to do more than just check the logical disk structure or read the SMART statistics: it will have to scan all your hard disk sectors for readability. That will allow the SMART subsystem to reallocate bad sectors. I know [Spinrite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) does this (may be other programs as well, but I don't know them).